# How to replace a password in /etc/shadow using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For my security class we are supposed to use a badly written file copying program to gain a root shell. We are supposed to write our hack into a script. I know how to get access to the /etc/shadow file but I am not sure how, from within a bash script, to search for the root password and replace it with no password. I know the format of the shadow file, username:password:etc, but is it possible in a script to find where the password is and replace it?

I have found the command `sed` but that requires me knowing what the old password is. Is there another command I could use before that to grab the password out?

Note: I am working with a copy of /etc/shadow that I can then overwrite the original with

Comment: you cannot read `/etc/shadow` unless you are `root`, so it is unlikely that you will end up getting root's password if you miss that point.

Comment: With the code he gave us,  I am able to get a copy of /etc/shadow, change it, and then write it back over the original. It's just the changing it part I am having trouble with

Comment: Have you an restore plan if you lock-out yourself? :) :)

Comment: Yeah, we are each working on our own virtual machine and we just have to email our teacher for a reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your root hash

```
pass=`cat /etc/shadow | grep root| awk -F: '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: can be just one command: `awk -F: '$1=="root" {print $2}' /etc/shadow`

Comment: So that would find the password associated with root and store it in pass? Obviously since I'm working with a copy of /etc/shadow (as mentioned in a comment above) I would just replace that part of your line with the name of my copy correct?

Comment: it will store the hash of root password, not the password itslef.

Comment: That should be fine, since I only want to replace it with no password and never care what the plaintext password is. Thanks so much! I'll try it out later and then accept your answer. Have a great day!

Comment: That will get hash of every username containing "root", not only root.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid parsing and using python/perl/awk/.... a possibile solution is to use the `usermod` command in this way:

```
usermod -R /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs -p `mkpasswd -m sha-512 lol` root
```

In the above example I specified a different chroot (`-R`) and i used **lol** as password.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this and explain what you are doing here as opposed to posting plain code please?